# Spring: Can't load the application context. NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, applicationcontext

i hope anybody might had a solution for this.
I implemented a simple test to check if the application context starts correctly, but all i get is an NoSuchBeanDefinition Exception.

So i had a closer look to the ctx-*.xml files. Sadly i had found nothing.

thx in advance

***The test preparation:***

```
package de.backend.services;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import de.garfield.backend.persistence.services.interfaces.OCHEntryService;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/META-INF/spring/ctx-backend.xml"})
public class OCHEntryServiceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    private OCHEntryService ochEntryService;

    /** Tests if the application context could be loaded. **/
    @Test
    public void loadApplicationContext() {
        ochEntryService.findAll();
    }
}
```

***The exception:***

```
2014-12-23 22:02:53,340 [main] ERROR org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager  - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@5093acc2] to prepare test instance [de.backend.services.OCHEntryServiceImplTest@67591ba4]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'OCHEntryServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private de.backend.repositories.OCHEntryRepo de.backend.services.OCHEntryServiceImpl.ochEntryRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [de.backend.repositories.OCHEntryRepo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private de.backend.repositories.OCHEntryRepo de.backend.services.OCHEntryServiceImpl.ochEntryRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [de.backend.repositories.OCHEntryRepo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:558)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [de.backend.repositories.OCHEntryRepo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:530)
    ... 43 more
```

---

### Additional files

***Entity class:***

```
package de.backend.entities;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class OCHEntry {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String source;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date created;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String link;

    // getter, setter, hashCode, equals, toString
}
```

***Repository:***

```
package de.backend.repositories;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import de.backend.entities.OCHEntry;

@Repository
public interface OCHEntryRepo extends JpaRepository<OCHEntry, Long> {

    List<OCHEntry> findAllOrderByCreated();

    List<OCHEntry> findByTitleLike(String searchCriteria);

    List<OCHEntry> findByLinkLike(String searchCriteria);

    List<OCHEntry> findAllBySource(String source);
}
```

***Service Interface:***

```
package de.backend.services.interfaces;

import java.util.List;

import de.backend.entities.OCHEntry;

public interface OCHEntryService {

    List<OCHEntry> findAllOrderByCreated();

    List<OCHEntry> findAllBySource(String source);

    List<OCHEntry> findByTitleLike(String searchCriteria);

    List<OCHEntry> findByLinkLike(String searchCriteria);

    List<OCHEntry> findAll();

    void save(OCHEntry ochEntry);
}
```

***Service implementation:***

```
package de.backend.services;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import de.backend.entities.OCHEntry;
import de.backend.repositories.OCHEntryRepo;
import de.backend.services.interfaces.OCHEntryService;

@Service
public class OCHEntryServiceImpl implements OCHEntryService {

    @Autowired
    private OCHEntryRepo ochEntryRepo;

    public List<OCHEntry> findAllOrderByCreated() {
        return this.ochEntryRepo.findAllOrderByCreated();
    }

    public List<OCHEntry> findByTitleLike(String searchCriteria) {
        return this.ochEntryRepo.findByTitleLike(searchCriteria);
    }

    public List<OCHEntry> findByLinkLike(String searchCriteria) {
        return this.ochEntryRepo.findByLinkLike(searchCriteria);
    }

    public List<OCHEntry> findAll() {
        return this.ochEntryRepo.findAll();
    }

    public void save(OCHEntry ochEntry) {
        this.ochEntryRepo.save(ochEntry);
    }

    @Override
    public List<OCHEntry> findAllBySource(String source) {
        return this.ochEntryRepo.findAllBySource(source);
    }
}
```

***ctx-backend:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="de.backend.*" />

    <!-- Import datasource -->
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/spring/ctx-datasource.xml" />

</beans>
```

***ctx-datasource:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c" xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:repository="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-1.7.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.1.xsd">

    <alias name="jpaVendorAdapterMySql" alias="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapterMySql"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
        <property name="showSql" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="username" value="${mysql.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${mysql.password}" />
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${mysql.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${mysql.url}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="de.backend.entities.*" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <jpa:repositories base-package="de.backend.repositories.*" />

    <bean id="datasourcePropertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="datasource.properties" />
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="transactionTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

***pom.xml - dependencies:***

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Database (H2) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- DataSource (HikariCP) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JPA Provider (Hibernate) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.dirrot.dev.parsers</groupId>
        <artifactId>portal-parsers</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

## Solution:

The main problem was, that the declaration of the "query by method name" syntax didn't worked. So i altered some methods. And now it works.

***ctx-backend:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <!-- Import datasource -->
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/spring/ctx-datasource.xml" />

    <context:annotation-config />
    <jpa:repositories base-package="de.backend.epositories" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="de.backend.services" />

</beans>
```

and

***OCHEntryRepo:***

```
@Repository
public interface OCHEntryRepo extends JpaRepository<OCHEntry, Long> {

    List<OCHEntry> findAll(Sort sort);

    List<OCHEntry> findByTitleContaining(String searchCriteria);

    List<OCHEntry> findByLinkContaining(String searchCriteria);

    List<OCHEntry> findBySource(String source);

}
```

BIG THANKS TO ALL INVOLVED !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="de.backend.repositories" />
```

into your ctx-backend.xml before the

```
<context:compnent-scan>.
```

Please rename

```
 List<OCHEntry> findAllBySource(String source);
```

into

```
 List<OCHEntry> findBySource(String source);
```

and

```
 List<OCHEntry> findAllOrderByCreated();
```

into

```
 List<OCHEntry> findAllOrderByCreatedDesc();
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Could you please try the repositories with jpa: prefix? If that does not help then with the repository? According to spring docs it shall be the "http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" namespace, which has in your setup the jpa: prefix.

Comment: Still getting the same exception. And i also looked into the docs.

Comment: Do you see the repositories scan? With log4j configured to DEBUG it produces quite a output.

Comment: I added my log output [here](https://gist.github.com/Dirrot/eb719906fd4544a46993)

Comment: The problem is with one (or more) of your methods in the repository. Could you try to comment out one method after other until the context can be booted successfully?

Comment: Perhaps findAllBySource() ? Also not sure whether findAllOrderByCreated shall not be findAllOrderByCreatedDesc  or findAllOrderByCreatedAsc. You need to try.

Comment: I've allready done that. Even if i comment out every method in my repo interface the same exception occurs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67754/discussion-between-michal-and-dirk-rother).

Comment: I set the <jpa:repository ...> before the <context:component-scan ...> and i also altered the spring query by method name declaration.